# (Selenium) (C#) How can I automatically open the Chrome DevTools tab in Mobile View within Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

Following this post:

[How do you automatically open the Chrome Devtools tab within Selenium (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683576/how-do-you-automatically-open-the-chrome-devtools-tab-within-selenium-c)

Is there anyway to open Chrome browser with DevTools opened and Mobile view toggled?

Thanks in advance!

Tried to open with DevTools open and with EnableEmulation with a specific device (Pixel 5) but it simply open it in the device's resolution with DevTools open.